# CSS3 transform scaleX not changing text

Tags: css

I want to make a menu that slides to the right when mousing over it. However, when I remove my mouse, I want it to go back in the same rate as it did out.

Here's my code:

```css
.item {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #A14B00;
 height: 2em;
 width: 17vw;
 margin-bottom: 0.5em;
 margin-left: -12vw;
 line-height: 2em;
 padding-left: 13vw;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-size: 2em;
 font-family: "League Gothic", "bebas neue", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
}

@-webkit-keyframes itemHover{
 0% { padding-right: 0vw; }
 100% { padding-right: 3vw; }
}
@-moz-keyframes itemHover{
 0% { padding-right: 0vw; }
 100% { padding-right: 3vw; }
}
@-o-keyframes itemHover{
 0% { padding-right: 0vw; }
 100% { padding-right: 3vw; }
}
@keyframes itemHover{
 0% { padding-right: 0vw; }
 100% { padding-right: 3vw; }
}

.item:hover {
 -webkit-animation: itemHover 1s;
 -moz-animation: itemHover 1s;
 -o-animation: itemHover 1s;
 animation: itemHover 1s;
 color: #000000;
 padding-right: 3vw;
}
```

snippet to avoid a fight with the website-code

http://jsfiddle.net/ddrekkf9/3/

Could someone suggest a solution, that doesn't run an animation in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animation jumps, as it is only defined to animate for "hover", but not back to *normal state*.

You may not need an animation (see below). Change it to a **transition**. To produce smooth changes *to a given value* and *back again*, **assign this transition to the selector in general and define just the padding for hover**.

Change to

```
.item {
   -webkit-transition: padding-right 1s;
   -moz-transition: padding-right 1s;
   -o-transition: padding-right 1s;
   transition: padding-right 1s;
}
.item:hover {
    color: #000000;
    padding-right: 3vw;
}
```

and it works. Check out this updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ddrekkf9/4/

In fact, animations are prefered, if you want to change one property to multiple values over a time, e.g. change padding to 10px to 10% of given time, then to 30px for 20% of time and slow down to 60px at another remaining time to 100%. It seems, you don't need this.